# Erasing numbers from circle and writing down sum

Tags: combinatorics, parity

There are $50$ copies of the number $1$, and $50$ copies of the number $-1$, written *alternately* in a circle. In each step, we pick an arbitrary number, write down the sum of the number and its two neighbors on another piece of paper, and erase that number. We do this until there are only $2$ numbers left. Prove that we will write down an even number of positive numbers.

I can show that for one particular sequence of erasing, the statement is true. If we erase the numbers consecutively $1,-1,1,-1,\ldots$, we always write down the number $-1$, which means we write down an even  number (i.e., none) of positive numbers. How can this be extended to an arbitrary sequence of erasing?

Comment: Do you erase the two neighbors as well? If not, you'll never be left with $2$ numbers.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 No, we only erase one number at a time, until we're left with $2$ numbers. (After $98$ times of erasing we'll reach that point.)

Comment: Ahh, I see. For some reason, I thought the new number was written on the circle (as opposed to somewhere else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalization: any number of $1$s and $-1$s are written in a circle in any order, and the same steps are performed. We claim that the number of positive numbers written down has the same parity as the number of pairs of consecutive $1$s in the original circle. (For example, if there are four $1$s in a row flanked by $-1$s, that counts as three pairs of consecutive $1$s.)

The generalization is easy to prove inductively, since the only moves that change the number of pairs of consecutive $1$s are to remove a $-1$ that's between two $1$s or to remove a $1$ that has a $1$ as a neighbor, both of which result in writing a positive number down.